# Autosize TextBox width on load -> then fix size

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, width, autosize

This is a kind of newbie question to wpf using C#.

I have a `TextBox`, where the user may enter a time. As the font size may differ I want the `TextBox` to autosize to its initial value "00:00:00" on load of the form.

After that, I do not want resizing, because it looks strange if the `TextBox` resizes on user input.

Currently I am defining in xaml file:

```
<TextBox Text="00:00:00" Name="myTextBox" />
```

Doing so, the TextBox will autosize to the current content.

To prevent it from resizing after the form is visible, I use:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Width = myTextBox.ActualWidth;
}
```

This gives me the desired result.

However, is the same possible just by setting xaml properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine the width of your text with the current font, and set that size to a `TextBox` width. You can measure the text width using the `FormattedText` class (see [FormattedText Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext_methods.aspx)).

Comment: This would involve coding as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing this in XAML is that when binding the `Width` to the `ActualWidth`, the initial  value of `ActualWidth` is usually 0. So it will set your width to 0.

This can easily be solved by using a `Converter`.

So create your `TextBox` like this:

```
<TextBox Text="00:00:00" Name="myTextBox" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource widthConverter}}" />
```

Now your converter should be something like this:

```
class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {  
        double actualWidth;

        if (Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out actualWidth))
        {
            if (actualWidth> 0)
            {
                return actualWidth;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In other words, only return the `ActualWidth` if it's > 0.

The converter will actually be called twice, the second time with the correct value and that is what will be set in the textbox's `Width` property.

Comment: Thats incorrect, `ActualWidth` returns the rendered size of the control, it will only be 0 if you explicitly set the `Width` to 0. If you don't set `Width` on a control the `Width` will always be `Double.NaN`.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I just checked it again to make sure - I get 0.0 as the value of ActualWidth on the first call to the converter...

Comment: Thats why OP has the code in his loaded event, to make sure the Textbox is loaded(content) before setting the `Width` to `ActualWidth`, But won't the converter set the width of the textbox if the ActualWidth changes? ie: longer text is entered?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - Longer text does not trigger a change in the ActualWidth property. You can try it for yourself :)

Comment: Interesting complex approach. But this is not "pure" XML. I was looking more for some kind of setting. For me it is easier to stick to my one line of extra code.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein - It all depends on what you need :) If your application is MVVM oriented this might be a better approach (just for the sake of clarity). It *is* possible to do in XAML, but yeah, a converter is also needed for additional logic. This is due to the fact that binding happens before the Loaded event is raised...